# lower tail z-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, z-test

This is an exercise from Freedman, Pisani and Purves’ Statistics, 4th ed. (p. 552/8)

> An investigator has independent samples from box A and from box B. Her null hypothesis says that the two boxes have the same average. She looks at the difference
>
> ```
>      average of sample from A – average of sample from B.
> ```
>
> The two-sample z-test gives z = about 1.79. Is the difference statistically significant if the alternative hypothesis says that the average of box A is
>   a)  bigger than the average of box B?
>   b)  smaller than the average of box B?
>   c)  different from the average of box B?

EDIT: I have found the English version of the book, so have deleted my previous version translated from Hungarian in order to avoid any misunderstandings that could be caused by wording.

My solutions to the questions are
a) yes, as p = 3.6%
b) no, as p = 3.6%
c) no, as p = 7.2%

But according to the book's solution b) is incorrect *because* p = 96%. Is this a mistake? If not, then why is such a high p value given? In my understanding the area of the bell-shaped curve between z = 1.79 and -1.79 should be considered as evidence that the average of box A is the same as box B (or in a precise language: "We reject the counter hypothesis that the average of box A differs from the average of box B") because the observed difference is small, it could be due to chance error. Thus, it would be only the tiny left chunk area under the curve (z <= -1.79) that would support a hypothesis that the average of box A is lower than box B.

What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: p is relative to the hypothesis being tested.   In question b, the null hypothesis is that the average of box A $\geq$ the average of box B, so the p-value is based on the probability of seeing the given z-value or a *lower* one.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree. According to the exercise, the null hypthothesis is the same in all three cases, only the counter hypothesis varies (if that is possible at all).

Comment: Well there is a philosophical issue about whether your null + your alternative should cover all the possibilities, but, setting that aside, your alternative is different - and the p-value is calculated "in the direction of" whatever the alternative is, so to speak.  So, if the alternative is that $\mu_A > \mu_B$, then the p-value is calculated with an eye as to whether the difference is large in a positive direction, but if the alternative is that $\mu_A < \mu_B$, then the p-value is calculated with an eye as to whether the difference is large in a negative direction...

Comment: If your $z$-score is 1.79, in the former case we care about the probability of seeing a higher z-score: $p = 0.036$.  In the latter case we care about the probability of seeing a lower z-score: $p = 0.964$.

Comment: Calculating the p-value in the direction of "whatever the alternative is," makes sense. Still I find it confusing that we count the central area under the curve (z=2) twice: once to reject the null hypothesis, and then to strengthen the case for our alternative hypothesis. Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: How do we count it twice?  We are only doing one test: is the observed value of the test statistic as extreme or more extreme (in the direction of the alternative, if the alternative is one-sided) than we would expect it to be with some probability $\alpha$ if the null hypothesis is true.

Comment: I somehow thought that anything within z=2 was always related to the null hypothesis, and only the area that was beyond 2 could be counted towards the alternative. But now I realise that we just have one question, which is: If the null hypothesis is true, then what is the probability that we get such a difference or a higher/lower one? Where "higher" is used when we expect a positive difference between the null and alternative hypothesis, and "lower" when we expect a negative difference between them. This is how I would put it, laically, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That makes total sense and is correct!